# MDX subtract measures across dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

```
WITH 
  MEMBER CostDifference AS 
    Sum([Measures].[ExtendedCost]) - [Measures].[ExtendedCost] 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[ExtendedCost]     
     ,CostDifference
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Parts].[ItemDesc].MEMBERS, [Dim Date].[DateUK].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

I'm trying to subtract a measures across different dimensions i.e. for 2 date snapshots (31/1/2010 and 28/2/2010) for all the products in DimParts

if I remove this piece of code from equation then all I get is zeros 
`[Dim Date].[DateUK].MEMBERS`

If I use a cross join to add more than one dim even then the cost difference is zero

`e.g. ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [Parts].[ItemDesc].MEMBERS
     ,{[Dim Date].[DateUK]}
    ) ON ROWS`

I'm using SQl Server 2008R2

What am I missing here.

Comment: well this will always be the case!! ... `[Measures].[ExtendedCost] - [Measures].[ExtendedCost] = 0`

Comment: But I'm adding dim to the equation so that i takes different dates into calculation, is the thought process wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `Sum([Measures].[ExtendedCost]) - [Measures].[ExtendedCost]` 
Will resolve to this

```
[Measures].[ExtendedCost] - [Measures].[ExtendedCost]
```

Which is always 0

If this `Sum([Measures].[ExtendedCost])` needs to be across a complete set then you need to include that set:

```
Sum(
  [Dim Date].[DateUK].MEMBERS
 ,[Measures].[ExtendedCost]
)
```

Comment: Thanks @whytheq I get an error in the result set "#Error The function expects a string or numeric expression for the argument. A tuple set expression was used." But if i use [Dim Date].[DateUK].&[31/1/2010 ] I do get results... So can I make it generic, can I?

Comment: this is from your script `[Dim Date].[DateUK].MEMBERS` ....members returns a set so I don't know why you get that error